Error in tmp[names.long, ] <- X.p : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
I am using the spOccupancy library in R to run a multi-species spatial occupancy model, using the spMsPGOcc() function, as follows:
out.spatial.mult <- spMsPGOcc(occ.formula = MultSpec_Occ_Formula, 
                       det.formula = MultSpec_Det_Formula,
                       data = new.dat.mult, 
                       n.batch = 400, 
                       n.burn = 5000, 
                       n.thin = 5, 
                       batch.length = 25,
                       n.chains = 3,
                       n.report = 20,
                       k.fold = 5,
                       k.fold.threads = 4)

Where
The model ran for its entire run, but after it completed the last batch, in the last chain, I got this:
Error in tmp[names.long, ] <- X.p : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Looking on github, where the source code for this R library is archived (https://github.com/doserjef/spOccupancy/blob/main/R/spMsPGOcc.R#L1975), this is the only reference I found to tmp[names.long, ] <- X.p
  if (!binom) {
    tmp <- matrix(NA, J * K.max, p.det)
    tmp[names.long, ] <- X.p

There are several cases of tmp <- and X.p <- in this code, but I think that they all ultimately refer back to this near the begining:
tmp <- parseFormula(det.formula, data$det.covs)
X.p <- as.matrix(tmp[[1]])

There are several different pardFormula() functions across various R libraries, and I am not sure which one is used in this function. If I did, I would try to repeat this is my data to see what is the issue here.
Can anyone tell me what the issue here is, and if there is even a theoretical way to solve it by changing some of the setting in the spMsPGOcc() function?
